# How does the VM pick the correct method to execute?

Tags: java, android

This question is based on an Android scenario, but it's applicable to Java in general.

In Android, the `ContentValues` class has many `put()` methods, including:

```
put(String key, Float value)
put(String key, Integer value)
```

Our code has:

```
contentValues.put(myKey, myCondition ? Utils.getFloat(something) : Utils.getInt(something));
```

We've observed that when this is executed, it's always `put(String key, Float value)` that is invoked. This happens even if the ternary operator resolves to an integer value because `myCondition` is not satisfied.

In our case, replacing this with an `if-else` solves the problem. I'm really asking for an explanation of when and how the VM selects the method to be executed.

If this has already been answered, please mark it as a duplicate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not VM ... compiler ... and now everything should be clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method overloading is resolved at compile-time, not runtime. <s>The type of the ternary expression is `Number` -- presumably there is a `put(String key, Number value)` method or a `put(String key, Object value)` method.</s> Edit: I am informed it is in fact coerced to Float. The JLS [describes this in more detail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9).

Other languages **do** resolve overloads at runtime. This feature is known as [double-dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch), since a method is *doubly* dispatched, first by argument type and then by self type.

Comment: The result of the ternary expression will be a Float

Comment: Makes sense. Just so everybody who reads this is aware, there isn't a put(String key, Number value). Nor is there a put(String key, Object value). See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html

Comment: @damo You know, I put that at first, but then I couldn't remember if Java actually coerced types like that for numbers.

Comment: Yep, it does a [binary numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) (see the last bullet)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the compiler (not the VM) selects the first method, the one with the value type of Float because the type of the expression

```
myCondition ? Utils.getFloat(something) : Utils.getInt(something)
```

is of type float (assuming that *getFloat* returns a *float* and *getInt* returns an *int*, if they are box types this wouldn't work as the type of the expression would be *Number*). This is determined at compile time by the compiler through type promotion (e.g. the integer expression *getInt* is converted to a float-type expression).

Comment: what if the order of the values after the "?" would be the opposite?

Comment: The type of the expression is the type of the expression after the '?'.

Comment: @androiddeveloper The order does not matter. The compiler will always promote an int to a float in this situation. This makes sense since converting a float to int would result in loss of precision.

Comment: @EJP No, the type of the ternary expression depends on both the expression after the '?' and the expression after the ':'.

Comment: so... i don't understand. what is the correct answer to the question i've asked?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Sorry, the type would still be float.

Comment: @hacim  no matter the order?